Performing unit testing for writhing the file to S3
i need to write the unit testing for uploading the file to S3 for the below code
def writetos3(df_meta, destination_bucket, metadacontrolfileloc):
        csv_string = df_meta.to_string(index=False)
        s3_client.put_object(Bucket=destination_bucket, Key=metadacontrolfileloc, Body=csv_string)

i wrote a code for this but i am getting the invalid token below is my code
class TestWritetoS3(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('utils.boto3.client')  # Patch boto3.client where it is imported in utils.py
    def test_writetos3(self, mock_boto_client):
        # Create a mock S3 client
        mock_s3_client = MagicMock()
        mock_boto_client.return_value = mock_s3_client

        # Create a DataFrame for testing
        df_meta = pd.DataFrame({
            'count': [10],
            'file_name': ['test_file'],
            'file_prefix': ['test_prefix'],
            'table': ['test_table'],
            'delimiter': ['|'],
            'file_format': ['csv']
        })

        # Define bucket and file location
        destination_bucket = 'test-bucket'
        metadacontrolfileloc = 'path/to/metadata_file.csv'

        # Call the function
        Utils.writetos3(df_meta, destination_bucket, metadacontrolfileloc)

        # Prepare the expected CSV string
        expected_csv_string = df_meta.to_string(index=False)

        # Debug: Print the actual call to put_object
        print(f"Mock S3 Client Calls: {mock_s3_client.method_calls}")

        # Assert that the put_object method was called with correct parameters
        mock_s3_client.put_object.assert_called_once_with(
            Bucket=destination_bucket,
            Key=metadacontrolfileloc,
            Body=expected_csv_string
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

and for this i am getting like this as a error
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the PutObject operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.
